# How to run Ansible playbook with source from internet by command line?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook named `playbook.yml` located on a website with a URL. Is it possible to run this playbook via the command line interface (CLI), without having to make changes to the local playbook?

Normally, I use the command `ansible-playbook /local/path/to/playbook` to run a playbook.

I do not want to change any of local playbook to finish this. I need to run additional playbook to an environment and do not have permission to change that environment.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is your question. Do you want to run playbook like ansible-playbook http://my.website.com/unchangable-playbook.yml? If so I am no aware of this feature of Ansible, but I am sure it can be easily predownloaded and executed afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `STDIN` for this assuming `curl`/`wget` is installed on the machine (or some other way to fetch the playbook).

```bash
curl https://my.server.com/playbook.yml | ansible-playbook -i inventory/ /dev/stdin
```

```bash
wget -O - https://my.server.com/playbook.yml | ansible-playbook -i inventory/ /dev/stdin
```

This might not work nicely with prompting for user-input if your playbook uses that. Not sure.

Comment: Indeed, such approach is working, as well something like `cat main.yml | ansible-playbook /dev/stdin` (_annot.: tested, ok_), However, someone has to consider if [Is `curl {something} | sudo bash -` a reasonably safe installation method?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/213401/), or here in this case an execution method.